# MVC accessing WCF shared service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I'm trying to access a WCF service in my MVC project. I added the shared service, i used this tutorial: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/krishnasarala/accessing-wcf-service-in-Asp-Net-mvc-application/

Now i'm having issues making an instance of it. I called my reference "ServiceReference1".

```
ServiceReference1.ServiceAuthorClient obj = new ServiceReference1.ServiceAuthorClient();
```

But i keep getting the namespace could not be found.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added reference to service?

Answer (score 0):

couple of things to try

1 - do you have System.ServiceModel referenced in the MVC project.

2 - Go to your ServiceReference - press the show all files button at the top of the solution explorer - you should see Reference.cs under the service reference. Look in here for the namespace, and generally check it has the right auto generated code.